# Reconsider the restrictions on editing an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I am trying to edit [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/429066/122849), because the last person to edit it (not the original poster) broke the link.

It is currently:

```
[another Windows Seven Forums website](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/22147-slow-login.htm) also confirm this.
```

To fix it, I'm trying to change it to:

```
[another Windows Seven Forums website](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/22147-slow-login.html) also confirm this.
```

But when trying to save, I get:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

There isn't anything else I want to do to improve the post, just to fix the link so it doesn't broken (it currently links to the homepage of sevenforums.com instead of the topic).

Now, I don't use Superuser that much. I know my edit will going into the queue, but I can't even get it into the queue and I don't think I'll be using Superuser that often to get enough rep to bypass the queue. I also don't have a way to comment on the answer to notify people what the correct link is.

Could situations like this (new users trying to make a constructive edit on a SE site they don't use) be reconsidered so we have a possible way to actually make a change like this? Or am I missing a way to go about filing this change with my current rep?

Or how about the character limit is ignored if the editor is changing a URL?

Or if changing SE for this isn't plausible, what should users do in this situation? I could not comment, I could not flag, I could not edit; and it's been unfixed for 4 or 5 days and possibly never fixed by another user who could actually make that edit.

Comment: I've fixed the link now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm often annoyed by the 6-char edit requirement, too, but it won't be changed any time in the foreseeable future.

Your options are:

1. Make additional changes to the post, to get above the 6-char limit
2. Leave a comment describing your change, so the OP or someone else with more rep can make the change (requires 50 rep).
3. Flag the post for moderator attention, and describe your suggested edit (requires 15 rep).

If you don't have enough rep to leave a comment yet, then earn some more rep with other, more substantial edits, or if you feel your edit is important enough, you can flag a moderator (option #3 above) to do the edit for you. I would only resort to a flag in the case of "really important" edits.

Comment: I don't have the ability to comment either, it seems. All I see is a "feedback" yes/no button.

Comment: You need to have at least 10 (or is it 15?) rep to leave comments.

Comment: 50 rep for commenting

Comment: What would you consider "really important"? Does flagging a post require a certain rep as well? I don't see it.

Comment: @JBurace: That's a judgment call. I suppose for me, I'd consider it "important" if, without the edit, the post is factually wrong or unusable in some way.  A broken URL might qualify.

Comment: @JBurace: The [flagging privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) requires `15` rep.

Comment: @JBurace Are you sure you are logged in? Those buttons are seen from users who are not logged in.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Hmm, yeah I am logged in on SuperUser. At the top it says `JBurace 8 * 3 | chat | meta | about | faq` but each answer only has `feedback ... Was this post useful to you?` under it.

Comment: Please, don't flag for moderation attention for something that can be done from normal users.

Answer (score 3):

Even though your edit seems to be a good one, there are several reasons for not allowing single character edits in general:

- usually, a post with a spelling error actually has several. Fix some more!
- it takes **two** higher rep users to review your edit. They have limited time and **a limited number of votes per day**. Using a vote each for a single character edit seems a bit wasteful.
- the review queue is often *full* of suggested edits making more substantial changes. Why waste one of my votes on a missing "l"? :-)
- a user with full edit privileges an make the edit herself without a review. Let her, it only takes one user and no votes!

A good plan is to edit  posts with worse problems, ask some questions and write some answers. In no time you will earn rep enough to do any edits you want.